# Configuring Maven repositories?

Tags: maven

I’m trying to configure Maven to be used inside my company. However, i reach the phase in which I must configure the repositories to be used.

- The common configuration for all user is set in the setting.xml file
  under MAVEN_HOME
- A user’s configuration  is set in the setting.xml file under
  USER_HOME.
- A project’s special configuration is set in the pom.xml

In my case, the second type of configuration should be used (A configuration for each user). However, a mismatch occurs while having a look at the Maven documentation. There is 2 cases either to use a `<mirrors>` or `<repositories>`  under a default profile.
What is the recommended and in case the 2 are set what's the one it will be taken by Maven engine **http://repository.poo/** or **http://repository.foo/** ?

```
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id> </id>
      <mirrorOf>* </mirrorOf>
      <name> </name>
       <url>http://repository.foo </url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

or

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
            <id> </id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id></id>
                    <name></name>
                    <url>http://repository.poo/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
```

Comment: if you want to configure for each user you have to use the second one

Comment: In your company you should start to use a repository manager than you can configure your settings.xml with [a single group](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.8/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html). Furthermore you shouldn't change the settings.xml file in the maven installation only the settings.xml in the users home folder `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` ..And you should never do special configuration related to repositories in your pom file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will almost certainly need the `<repositories>` if you have your own company repository and you want something other than the maven default.

You may need a mirror if you want to override something, for instance you may want to cache maven central artifacts in a local Nexus.

Take a look at https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

If in doubt leave the mirror.